# The equivalence between numbers and strings using a while loop

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm very new to coding. What would be the way to execute this using less lines of code?

```
for (var i=1; i <= 7; i++){
    if (i == 1) console.log("#");
       else if (i == 2) console.log("##");
       else if (i == 3) console.log("###");
       else if (i == 4) console.log("####");
       else if (i == 5) console.log("#####");
       else if (i == 6) console.log("######");
       else if (i == 7) console.log("#######");
}
```

I'ver been trying to use the while loop but I'm not understanding how to print multiple '#"s in less lines of code

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String#repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat):

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++){
    console.log('#'.repeat(i));
}
```